# Obtain characteristic function given another characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

**Preliminary Fact:** If $X$ is a random variable with double exponential density of parameter $\lambda$, i.e.

$$ f_X(x) = \frac{\lambda}{2} e^{-\lambda |x|}, ~~ x \in \mathbb{R} \tag{*} $$

Then the characteristic function of X is

$$ \phi_X(t) = \frac{\lambda^2}{\lambda^2 + t^2}, ~~ t \in \mathbb{R} \tag{1} $$

**Problem:** Let X be a random variable with density given by

$$ f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}, ~~ x \in \mathbb{R} \tag{2} $$

Use the preliminary fact above to conclude that

$$ e^{-|x|} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ixt}\frac{1}{\pi(1 + t^2)}dt \tag{3} $$

**Thoughts:** The only thing I can see here is that in the expresion above $(3)$, on the RHS we have the Fourier transform of a standard Cauchy density, so on the LHS that must be the characteristic function of the standard Cauchy density. But I have idea how I'm supposed to use the preliminary fact $(*)$ to conclude $(3)$.

Comment: Well, the characteristic function of $X$ is $\frac1{1+t^2}$ which appears in the integrand. That might help.

Comment: @Math1000 i did it. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, could you type up your solution as an answer? That is the proper etiquette in this situation. Not only does it not leave an unanswered question, but it also serves to help people that come across the question via search.

Comment: @Math1000 I'll do that when I'm not busy studying for my probability calc exam tomorrow.